# My Java Script code does not seem to be able to be entred what am I missing

Tags: javascript, html

What am I missing in this code? When I try to run it it only gives the first "else if" alert. I cant find anything I have done wrong on Google(c) so I was wondering if the experts can have a look at my code. Is there a text box I need to add?

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>HTML5 Compliant Template</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script>
    var scoops = 5;
    if (scoops >= 5) {
      alert("Eat faster, the ice cream is going to melt!");
    } else if (scoops == 5) {
      alert("See a Doctor Now you may have diabeties");
    } else if (scoops == 4) {
      alert("Bit greedy dont you think");
    } else if (scoops == 3) {
      alert("Leave some for the other kids");
    } else if (scoops == 2) {
      alert("Going once!");
    } else if (scoops == 1) {
      alert("Going twice!");
    } else if (scoops == 0) {
      alert("Gone!");
    } else {
      alert("Still lots of ice cream left, come and get it.")
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

If I am doing something wrong please alert me.

Thank you Ben Guha

Comment: What do you **expect** from this code? If you set `scoops = 5`, there is only branch to be triggered

Comment: so what do I need to add

Comment: Only the first `if` will be triggered because `5 >= 5` is true. `When I try to run it it only gives the first "else if" alert` no your are wrong, it does not. What do you want to do ?

Comment: The question is still open: what should your code do? Why do you think that you need a text box? Can you explain from a user's point of view (not from your developer's POV) what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the wrong sequence. Though sequence should be as per input/output model you are keeping in mind.

Below should be the code--

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5 Compliant Template</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script>
            var scoops = 5;

            if (scoops == 0) {
                alert("Gone!");
            }else if (scoops == 1) {
                alert("Going twice!");
            }  else if (scoops == 2) {
                alert("Going once!");
            } else if (scoops == 3) {
                alert("Leave some for the other kids");
            }else if (scoops == 4) {
                alert("Bit greedy dont you think");
            } else if (scoops == 5) {
                alert("See a Doctor Now you may have diabeties");
            } else  if (scoops >= 5) {
                alert("Eat faster, the ice cream is going to melt!");
            } else {
                alert("Still lots of ice cream left, come and get it.")
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How does your code run different from the OP's code?

Comment: In my answer I have mentioned that the mental model , "Though sequence should be as per input/output model you are keeping in mind. " ,this line. That's my thought of comparing smaller to bigger ones , it does differently cause , he is using  if (scoops >= 5) and below that its if (scoops == 5), thats wrong anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a form and from the question it seems like you really need to know some basic knowledge about html you should try some tutorials like [this.](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Here is the code that should do what you want. Form tag creates a form and takes as attribute an function name that should be executed on submit. 
Input tag creates a field with type set to number indicating that the input is a number.
And last a button with type set to submit indicating it will submit the form.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>HTML5 Compliant Template</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script>
    function validate(){
      var scoops = document.getElementById("scoops").value;
      if (scoops >= 5) {
        alert("Eat faster, the ice cream is going to melt!");
      } else if (scoops == 5) {
        alert("See a Doctor Now you may have diabeties");
      } else if (scoops == 4) {
        alert("Bit greedy dont you think");
      } else if (scoops == 3) {
        alert("Leave some for the other kids");
      } else if (scoops == 2) {
        alert("Going once!");
      } else if (scoops == 1) {
        alert("Going twice!");
      } else if (scoops == 0) {
        alert("Gone!");
      } else {
        alert("Still lots of ice cream left, come and get it.")
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<form onsubmit="validate()">
<span>Enter no. of scoops here</span>
<input id="scoops" type="number">
<button type="submit">
Submit
</button>
</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

html

`<input id='inputElement' type='number' onchange="updateInput()">`

Javascript

`var scoops=document.getElementById("inputElement").value
 // here you can use your if else logic`

Comment: Not an answer. More like a comment.

Comment: I want to add a box in which I can type the different digits from the "else if" statements.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
 <script>
    var scoops = 5;
    if (scoops > 5) { //this must be greater than, **not greater than or equal**
      alert("Eat faster, the ice cream is going to melt!");
    } else if (scoops == 5) {
      alert("See a Doctor Now you may have diabeties");
    } else if (scoops == 4) {
      alert("Bit greedy dont you think");
    } else if (scoops == 3) {
      alert("Leave some for the other kids");
    } else if (scoops == 2) {
      alert("Going once!");
    } else if (scoops == 1) {
      alert("Going twice!");
    } else if (scoops == 0) {
      alert("Gone!");
    } else {
      alert("Still lots of ice cream left, come and get it.")
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you test what happens if `scopes` is smaller then `5`?

Comment: it goes on related else/else if block. if scopes is 4 (a smaller number than 5), then it shows "Bit greedy dont you think" alert message. what do you expect?